# Cannot ssh into folder structure

Tags: server, ssh

I have a server `server.name`. With a folder `/home/user229472/folder`

I can use ssh like this:

```
ssh user229472@server.name
cd folder
...
```

scp works as well:

```
scp user229472@server.name:folder/file.txt .
```

But I cannot ssh directly into `folder`:

```
ssh user229472@server.name:folder
ssh: Could not resolve hostname server.name:folder: Name or service not known
```

I've tried lots of variations but none works:

```
 ssh user229472@server.name:22
 ssh user229472@server.name/
 ssh user229472@server.name/home/
 ssh user229472@server.name/home/user229472
 ssh user229472@server.name:/home
 ssh user229472@server.name:/home/
 ssh user229472@server.name:/home/user229472/folder
 ssh user229472@server.name:/folder
 ssh user229472@server.name:folder
```

Comment: None of those SSH commands make sense.`scp` is used to copy with files and folders, so it has syntax to deal directly with them. `ssh` is general purpose, so it doesn't have that because you can (and should) use commands anyway.

Comment: Ah shoot, I saw this as part of `git remote add origin username@server.name:path/myproject.git` and wanted to try it isolated first as part of debugging... everything works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ssh <user@server> -t 'cd <path to directory on remote server>; "$SHELL" -l'
```

In your case:

```
ssh user229472@server.name -t 'cd folder; "$SHELL" -l'
```

Comment: Instead of `bash --login`, `"$SHELL" -l` would be better. There's no guarantee the user's login shell is bash.

Comment: Updated as per suggestion from @muru

Answer (score 0):

Ssh gives you a login shell, after verifing your identity you will be logged in the remote system. After having done this you can use commands like  cd. If you want to mount a remote folder locally, use sshfs:
`sshfs user@remotehost:/path/to/remotefolder /path/to/localmountpoint`
Now you can acces the remotefolder via localmountpoint